# Constraints not working with ADBannerView

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, nslayoutconstraint

I've put an ADBannerView at the top of my app, but the banner view keeps covering up the SKView below it by about 10-20 pixels. I've checked the constraints in storyboard and they look fine - there's a vertical space constraint of 0 between the bottom of the ADBannerView and the SKView. Why is this not showing correctly?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ends up that I was initializing the scene with `initWithSize` using `self.view.bounds.size` in the view controller. This resized the scene to the wrong dimensions.